# control not available in current context

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn

I Applied a patch to a asp.net page using the tortoise svn "Apply Patch" command. The patch was created using the "Create patch" command.

The patch added a label control to the aspx page and some references to it in the codebehind. Now the solution just wont build unless I build the page seperately first. Sometimes even that wont work.

The page is perfectly valid asp.net and c# code that build and runs often. The only difference is that the code is added outside visualstudio, in tortoisemerge.

Any fixes

Comment: The file was already in the project. its just that a new control was added outside vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant explain why, but the problem was fixed after getting a fresh working copy from svn

Answer (score 0):

ask a silly question:)

you say it was added outside of VS. So have you included the files in your project / solutions.

Comment: The file was already in the project. its just that a new control was added outside vs